# Prove if the following is a vector space: V is the set of m x n matrices whose RREF contain a zero row

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove if the following is a vector space: V is the set of m x n matrices whose RREF contain a zero row

I an having trouble starting the question. I do know that the m x n matrices are in the set Rn and therefore can use the subset theory being A1 and M1 are true then it is a vector space. However given i dont have a "clear" matrix i am having troubles knowing where to start

Answer (score 2):

Bernard's matrix $B$ isn't in RREF, so his answer doesn't work.

An example that shows that the answer is in fact NO is $A = \pmatrix{1&1\cr 0&0\cr}$ and $B = \pmatrix{1&0\cr 1&0\cr}$. The RREF of $A$ is $A$, and the RREF of $B$ is $\pmatrix{1&0\cr 0&0\cr}$, but the RREF of $A+B$ is the identity matrix.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is ‘No’. Take $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$. Both are already in RREF, and have a zero row. However, their sum is the unit matrix.